# Kill pgAdmin 4 background process on Windows

Tags: pgadmin, pgadmin-4

I installed pgAdmin 4 on a Windows 8 machine and didn't like it so I uninstalled it, along with the C++ Runtime Redistributable Library (2015) that came with it. However, the web interface is still responding when I go to the URL of the admin:

http://127.0.0.1:57390/browser/

How do I kill this server process on my machine that's still running?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had to kill the "pg Desktop Runtime service" background process from my running tasks. Then the server stopped responding when I went to:

http://127.0.0.1:57390/browser/

But the install folder was still there so I had to delete it manually:

C:\Program Files (x86)\pgAdmin 4

Overall - a very sloppy uninstall because it:

1. doesn't kill the running server process
2. doesn't delete the
   install directory (C:\Program Files (x86)\pgAdmin 4)
3. doesn't
   delete the C++ Runtime Redistributable that it installs with pgAdmin